# Query redirect and clean up

Tags: php

I have been trying to get this working and watched other threads but nothing worked for me, 
i would like to redirect:
http://domain.net/stats.php?player=Matan

to:
http://domain.net/stats/Matan

Would that be possible?

Comment: You say _"I have been trying to get this working ..."_ what have you tried so far? Can you show that code?

Comment: you provide us nothing to work on. tell us what you tried and we can help further.

Comment: you should be able to do that in a htaccess file

Comment: `if (!empty($_GET['player'])) { header("Location: /status/".$_GET['player']); }` in `stats.php` is a quick solution to that in PHP, but you could possibly do it in `.htaccess` as well.

Comment: Use `.htaccess` or some extensions if you use CMS

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.htaccess` file with **mod_rewrite** [module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) enabled on Apache2

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^stats/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ stats.php?player=$1 [NC]
```

You can follow this simple tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite

In this case I used a simple **regex** in the *RewriteRule*, you can customize your regex whatever you like

EDIT: exceptions for static files

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(public|css)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
```

**please**, read the docs

Comment: Works! but now my external css file wont load, how can i fix that?

Comment: make exceptions for css js files extension